# Styled Components adding component name as class name

Tags: webpack, styled-components, storybook, preact

I'm using Preact with styled-components (storybook) and webpack to build my project

I have a component called `AlphaBarWrapper` with a styled component inside of it called `StyledAlphabar`.

Styled Components is adding `AlphaBarWrapper_StyledAlphaBar-sc-[random string]` as a classname to my component when rendered.

I'd like this to be the standard `sc-[random string]` class name instead. I can't find any documentation on why it is rendering this.

This occurs in both a standard webpack build and the storybook build, so I expect that there's an option that I'm missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If i'm right understood your issue you need install `babel-plugin-styled-components`. Then in the root directory create `.babelrc` and put this code:

```
{
  "plugins": [
    [
      "babel-plugin-styled-components",
      {
        "displayName": false, // generate other classname
        "fileName": false, // generate other classname
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

[documentation](https://styled-components.com/docs/tooling)

Comment: This fixed my issue, I added it to my `babel.config.json` instead. Thank you :)